# ASP.NET default login through WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm starting a new project and I'm also a little bit of new to ASP.NET and WCF services and right now I'm trying to understand the logic behind the ASP.NET login and registration functionality but I can't seem to figure it out exactly.

I want to make a WebApp using N-Layer architecture and I want presentation layer to be completely data-free and the default ASP.NET registration-login functionality doesn't let me do that since it access the database directly, at least not through some logic I want to do myself. What I'd like to do is to continue using the register-login functionality but instead of fetching for data directly to the database, I want it to be fetched from a WCF service, but I can't seem to find how to configure the register-login to do so.

Any idea where to start reading? I've read something about WCF Authentication but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There isn't as far as I know a `WCFMembershipProvider` or similar. This means that if you want to use build-in security features of ASP.NET you will need to create your own `MembershipProvider`.

Take a look at this tutorial it guide you on this process:

How to build a [custom membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479021.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'll surely take a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you would need to implement your own membership provider to use the service you have as the backing for authentication.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has resources on how to do this.

Additionally, you may want to ask yourself WHY you want this service to provide authentication.  What value does it give you?  Keep YAGNI and DRY principles at the forefront of your mind while thinking about it.

@Dalorzo beat me to it

Comment: Oh, well, I want to make a service to be accessed by both mobile application and web client, so if I keep the default login the database would be coupled to the presentation layer of the web client and that's not the idea. Am I right? I want both the app and the web client to access all information from the same place going through the service and a logic component I'm going to build. Although now I'm wondering if a WebService would work better than WCF for what I want to do. I don't really know the differences between both of them. What do you think could be best? Thanks in advance